# How to find the CDF of the sum of independent uniformly distributed random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$X,Y$ are independent random variables with uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, and let the random variable $Z=X+Y$.

The density of $Z$ is:
$$f_{X+Y}(z)=\int_0^z f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)dx$$

What is the formula for the probability $P(Z \leq m)$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Sorry, I have no attempt.

Comment: So you are nearly there. Have you computed the PDF? Once you have done that then compute the cdf and you are complete almost ;).

Comment: How can I compute the PDF?

Comment: You already have the method to compute the PDF using the convolution theorem. So that's what I meant by have you computed the pdf. :) once that's done you are nearly there. I also believe you will see it clearly once I place the hint down below.

Answer (score 2):

$\textbf{hint}$
$$
F(a) = P(X\leq a)
$$
Where $F(X)$ is the cdf.
The following is how to compute the cdf from a given pdf $f(x)$ 
$$
F(a) = \int^{a}_{x_{min}}f(x)dx 
$$
where the minimum of your support of the pdf is $x_{min}$ i.e for uniform random variable between 0 and 1, $x_{min}$ = 0.
Can you see how you can solve your problem?

it doesn't seem right generally and by that I mean

$f_Z(z) = \begin{cases}{
      z, \ \ \ \ 0\leq z < 1 \\  
      2-z, \ \ \  \ 1\leq z\leq 2 \\
      0, \ \ \ \  \text{otherwise}}
\end{cases}
$

ps. can someone reformat this horredous expression for me :).

So can you take it from there?

Comment: So I have to compute $F(m)$. Which is the formula? I have found this on wikipedia:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)#Cumulative_distribution_function

Comment: Is it $$F(m)=\int_{-\infty}^m f_{X+Y}(z)dz$$ ? Or is there an other $x_{min}$?

Comment: please, check edits to the hint. thanks

Comment: So I have to compute the integral $$\int_0^m f_{X+Y}(z)dz=\int_0^m \int_0^z f_X(x) f_Y(z-x) dx $$ and I'm done? How can I calculate this one?

Is $$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{1-0}=1$$ and $$f_Y(z-x)=\frac{1}{1-0}=1$$ ?

Comment: Or is it for the second one:

$$f_Y(z-x)=\frac{1}{z-(z-1)}=1$$ ?

Comment: So it is the answer:
$$\int_0^m \int_0^z dxdz=\int_0^m z dz=\frac{z^2}{2} |0^m=\frac{m^2}{2}$$ ?

Comment: so is the formula http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)#Probability_density_function not for this case?

Comment: You were close. But check my edits for the PDF. So now you can see that you will have different cdf depending on weather $0 \leq m\leq 1$ and similarly for the second case :).

Comment: What is the name of the formula of $f_{Z}(z)$ ?

Comment: Do we have triangular distribution and not the uniform? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution

Comment: If you have to put a name to it yes. But why do you have to the name the distribution? Ps sorry for the delay. :)

Comment: I didn't know this formula. Why do we have this type of distribution?